# What is index_col=0? and pd.index.name = None

Tags: python, pandas

```
'''
    import pandas as pd
    f500 = pd.read_csv('f500.csv',index_col=0)
    f500.index.name = None 
'''
```

I don't know what this mean.
What's roll of 'index_col=0'?
and 'f500.index.name = None'?

Comment: `index_col=0` menas parse first column to index, `f500.index.name = None` means set None to index name

Comment: Thx homie :) I thought they have another means :( Thx very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

For example you have a dataframe like this. If you want to have your index name to be some custom keyword you can you use the below command and it then will act as a single column

```
df.index.name = "your keyword"
```

[image]

The role of `index_col` is to say which column should act as an index.
For example if you want `BloodPressure` to be the index of the dataframe, the command will be like:

```
df.index_col = 2
```

[image]

The data of that column acts as index values so that we can access the dataframe using the `df.loc[]` commands

Answer (score 0):

index_col indicates what column of the csv to use as the indexes (row labels) of the dataframe.
for example:

*1,<field_1>,<field_2>,...*

*2,<field_1>,<field_2>,...
...*

if index_col is 0, in this case it means that "1" will be the index of the first column, "2" will be the index for the second column and so on.

---

If you have any other doubts like this you can refer to the pandas documentation.
Here is the link to the documentation for the read_csv method:
[link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)